# What happens when you try to free() already freed memory in c?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

For example:

```
char * myString = malloc(sizeof(char)*STRING_BUFFER_SIZE);
free(myString);
free(myString);
```

Are there any adverse side effects of doing this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's the chapter and verse.

> If the argument [to the `free` function] does not match a pointer earlier returned by the `calloc`, `malloc`, or
>   `realloc` function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`,
>   the behavior is undefined. ([ISO 9899:1999 - *Programming languages — C*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards), Section 7.20.3.2)

Comment: FYI: When C or C++ say "undefined" they usually mean "crash" or "memory corruption" or something equally terrible. Beware.

Comment: No, they really do mean "undefined." That just happens to include crashes and memory corruption.

Comment: @OrionEdwards The compiler could, for example, decide to launch NetHack.

Answer (score 20):

One of nothing, silent memory corruption, or segmentation fault.

Comment: Segfaults happen when you access memory that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can get a double free error that causes your program to crash. It has to do with malloc's internal data structures to keep track of allocated memory.

Answer (score 9):

Answer summary:

Yes, bad things can and probably will happen.

To prevent this do:

```
free(myString);
myString = NULL;
```

Note that all references to the memory must be set to `NULL` if others were created.

Also, calling `free()` with a `NULL` results in no action.  For more info see: [man free](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free)

Comment: Note that if you have made any copies of the pointer those should be set to NULL as well.

Comment: Seems like the community is leaning more towards putting answer summaries in the actual question, not as a question that is still buried...

Comment: Bad idea, since it's not applicable to const values. You do use const values where possible, don't you?

Answer (score 6):

Not so clever.  Google for double free vulnerabilities.  Set your pointer to `NULL` after freeing to avoid such bugs.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't write a wrapper to free that does this for you, the pointer is passed by value not reference. i.e. Free(void **p) {free(*p); *p = NULL;} This is not as easy to retool code with.

Comment: ajbl, use a macro.

#define freep(x) (free(x); x = 0;)

Comment: Bad idea, since it's not applicable to const values. You do use const values where possible, don't you?

Comment: @Steve: I know this is old, but didn't we elsewhere discuss that passing a const-qualified pointer to `free` is not valid (both conceptually and formally, unless you cast away the qualifier)? :-)

Comment: @R..: I'm talking about `char *const ptr = malloc(STRING_BUFFER_SIZE); ... ; free(ptr);`. I don't think that is either formally or conceptually invalid. After that, `ptr = 0;` isn't on the cards. So if you define a macro `freep` as Derek says, then you can't use it on `ptr`.

Answer (score 6):

It (potentially) makes [demons fly out of your nose](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons).

Answer (score 5):

Depending on which system you run it on, nothing will happen, the program will crash, memory will be corrupted, or any other number of interesting effects.

Answer (score 4):

*Bad Things* (TM)

Really, I think it's undefined so anything at all including playing "Global Thermonuclear War" with NORAD's mainframe

Answer (score 3):

Always set a pointer to NULL after freeing it.
It is safe to attempt to free a null pointer.

It's worth writing your own free wrapper to do this automatically.

Comment: Your free() wrapper must either be a macro or must use a different interface from the standard free() function.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that.  If the memory that got freed is re-allocated to something else between the calls to `free`, then things will get messed up.

Comment: Things will usually be messed up even if the memory is not reallocated between the two calls to free.

Answer (score 1):

It may crash your program, corrupt memory, or have other more subtle negative effects.  After you delete memory, it is a good idea to set it to NULL (0).  Trying to free a null pointer does nothing, and is guaranteed to be safe.  The same holds true for delete in c++.

Answer (score 1):

In short: "Undefined Behavior".

(Now, what that can include and why that is the case the others have already said. I just though it was worth mentioning the term here as it is quite common).

Comment: Google for 'nasal demons' to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

The admittedly strange macro below is a useful drop-in replacement for wiping out a few classes of security vulnerabilities as well as aid debugging since accesses to free()'d regions are more likely to segfault instead of silently corrupting memory.

```
#define my_free(x) do { free(x); x = NULL; } while (0)
```

The do-while loop is to help surrounding code more easily digest the multiple-statements.  e.g. if (done) my_free(x);

Comment: Wouldn't "#define my_free(x) { free(x); x = NULL; }" work just as well?

Comment: No, after expansion there's an illegal semicolon in 
if (done) {free(x); x=NULL}; else do_more();
Good luck finding the "else without matching if" error in your original source.

Comment: C has the comma operator for a reason. `#define my_free(x) (free((x)),(x)=0)`

Answer (score -1):

**Another interesting situation:**

```
char * myString = malloc(sizeof(char)*STRING_BUFFER_SIZE);
char * yourString = myString;

if (myString)
{
    free(myString);
    myString = NULL;
}
// Now this one is safe, because we keep to the rule for 
// setting pointers to NULL after deletion ...
if (myString)
{
    free(myString);
    myString = NULL;
}

// But what about this one:
if (yourString)
{
    free(yourString);
    yourString = NULL;
}

//?!? :)
```