# How free handles null pointer

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [checking for NULL before calling free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912325/checking-for-null-before-calling-free)
>   [What happens when you try to free() already freed memory in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135474/what-happens-when-you-try-to-free-already-freed-memory-in-c)

Hope this isn't a totally dumb question. Anyway...

What happens when a null pointer is passed to `free`.

Thank you!

P.S. What about a standard compliant allocator? Thanks again!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It immediately returns without doing anything.

Per 7.20.3.2, paragraph 3:

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. **If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs.** Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: I am so glad they changed the standard behavior to this. I remember when all calls to free where macros that wrapped the call to free in a test for NULL.

Comment: The standard has always required `free` to behave this way. The ugly wrappers were either based on urban legend or a desire to support some broken nonstandard pseudo-C implementations.

Comment: Quite possibly true. But I am older than the standard. Since the first C standard was `N119` published on `18 Jun 90`. I first used C in 87 and their definitely was a problem free a NULL pointer in the version we were using.

Answer (score 3):

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) says:

> free() frees the memory space pointed
>   to by ptr, which must have been
>   returned by a previous call to
>   malloc(), calloc() or realloc().
>   Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already
>   been called before, undefined
>   behaviour occurs. **If ptr is NULL, no
>   operation is performed.**

Comment: Keep in mind the man pages are non-normative, and often have POSIX specific extensions. They should not be relied upon as references for standard behavior.

Comment: Oh, dear.  Is there a different set of documentation that is normative?

Comment: Man pages never were normative. For C and C++, the respective ISO/IEC standards are normative. For POSIX, the POSIX standard itself is normative. Man pages describe how your particular machine (might) work(s), but not how to achieve standard behavior across machines. (Man pages usually *do* have references to the actual normative standards where applicable near the end)

Answer (score 1):

`free(ptr)` should do nothing if `ptr` is `NULL`.

In the real-world programming, this feature helps make your code even simpler like this:

```
class YourClass
{
public:

YourClass()
{
    m_ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    //Validate m_ptr and perform other initialization here
}

~YourClass()
{
    // You don't have to validate m_ptr like this
    // if (m_ptr)
    // {
    //     delete m_ptr;
    // }

    // Instead, just call free(m_ptr)
    // Notice: generally you should avoid managing the pointer by yourself,
    // i.e., RAII like smart pointers is a better option.
    free(m_ptr);
}

private:

int *m_ptr;
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest `auto_ptr` instead for this?

Comment: Don't write your own smart pointers. It is much harder than you think. This version of course fails because you have not followed the rule of three. But I went to a talk by Scott Meyers were he described his attempt at a smart pointer in one of his books. Even after multiple peer reviews when published he was getting e-mails about situations where it did not work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, you should use smart pointer in most cases without reinventing the wheel. But when you have to do that yourself, that's a useful knowledge. I'll update my answer, thanks both.