# C++ vulnerability issue with pointers

Tags: c++, security, memory-leaks

In a test document I found I got asked what the problem in following code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char* a = (char*) malloc (20);
    char* b = (char*) malloc (20);
    strcpy(b, "Secure Coding");
    strcpy(a, "Insecure Coding");
    a = b;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl << endl;
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

What is it?

Comment: Well, what do you think? Have you analyzed the code and what it does?

Comment: Also, it would help if you posted *compiling* code because right now, the problem with the code is that it doesn't compile. That, however, is nothing to do with security or "secure code".

Comment: Also, why have you tagged this question C#? That's not C# code, that's C or C++ code.

Comment: This is C# code? I must be doing it wrong...

Comment: Wrong tags, please fix.

Comment: It's not even C code since `<iostream>` and `cout` is used.  To the OP:  **C is not C++**.

Comment: Note that this isn't a security issue as much as it is a resource issue; this code has a memory leak.

Comment: @JohnBode: ITs also a security issue as there is undefined behavior. Caused be the result of the resource leak and some calls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a=b;
```

After this assignment **a** points to the same location as **b** ("Secure Coding"). You have lost any reference to the initial location pointed by **a**, so essentially "Insecure Coding" is garbage that cannot be freed.

Another issue is that you are freeing the same pointer twice. After the first free you no longer own that memory.

See: [What happens when you try to free() already freed memory in c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135474/what-happens-when-you-try-to-free-already-freed-memory-in-c)